How many times has StackExchange wrongly suspended someone for sockpuppet?
How many innocent users have StackExchange “wrongly accused and suspended for having sockpuppets”, but then “recovered with all the previous reputation and badges”? Are there other cases than following? Like cases resolved privately?
Does S.E. keep a record of false positives, wrongful suspensions?

This situation happened on the Workplace site a few years ago, where two co-workers at the same location were working together (one would think of a question and the other would answer it) - they mainly stuck to each other's questions and answers, so they were both suspended for sock-puppetry. After a meta discussion, an understanding was reached and accounts restored.

This sounds suspiciously like the times when SO mistook me for Yi Jiang and it mistook Yi Jiang for someone else, only other difference being we're in Singapore. Our theory was that our ISP was dealing us their server-side caches, because they're known to cache a wee bit too aggressively. Don't know about yours, though.

There was a hiccup in our network event aggregation. Those responsible have been properly chastised.


My business partner and I have separate accounts, separate email addresses, separate profiles, across several StackExchange sites. Mysteriously, we now see that his account was merged into mine. What's particularly scary is that we can both login to the same account using our individual Google accounts. His user name is "Quant Guy". We never use the same computer and would never give each permissions to the others account.


So it's the second time happening today. I enter the site and on the up-right other user's picture rep and badges appear. I clicked on it and it took me to his profile page, when on his page the up-right part with picture rep and badges turned to normal. It happened now and about 2 hours ago, and there were 2 different profiles. Why is this happening?


@Charles Certainly, I'm not denying that there were instances of false positives


I don't want (you) to solve a problem with this local-network-proxy-stuff, I just wonder if there is anything stackexchange can do to prevent such incidents.


For context, this user posted a question on Latin Language that was similar to that posted by a known troll. The mods there haven't disclosed whether this is the same troll or someone who happened to post similar things to them.

That's a lot of research for someone whose account has only been active for 4 days and is not the troll in question.

Every action taken is logged somewhere - but I don't think there's any numbers available publicly.
I'd probably point out that merges these days are done by the community team, but historically there were periods where it was done automatically or by moderators. Undoing a merge, as I understand needs developer time. SE's staff know and generally tends to try their best to minimise false positive merges - it's a bad look, a privacy nightmare, and a rather inefficient use of developer time.
Practically the reasons and systems for merges have changed so much over the last decade and half that even if you had the numbers, they're practically meaningless. Even with your example, some of them seem to be strange ISP edge cases.
IF your account was wrongly merged, contact the company via Contact Us, and they have the information to try to sort it out.
